# Magento SOAP API v2: Get currently logged in customer email address

Tags: magento, soap

Is it possible to get the currently logged in customer's email address using the SOAP API?
**I will NOT have the CustomerID.**

I will be calling this from our ExpressionEngine installation.

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: Yeah, right, that stuff is for rocket scientists. ;-)

Comment: At issue is that we cannot call Mage:App() from many of our EE templates and we need to know the currently loggedin customer's info.  Magento and EE do not play well together when it comes to sharing data and there is no straight SQL way of getting this info from Magento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This change in /code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer/Api.php should return the currently logged in customer with all their info. I cannot currently test because I don't have SOAP installed in my PHP 5.2.14 installation.

```
public function info($customerId, $attributes = null)
{
    // if we didn't pass a $customerId
    if (!$customerId) {
        // get current customer session
        $custsess = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        // if the customer is logged in
        if($custsess->isLoggedIn() == true) {
            // get their ID to load below
            $customerId = $custsess->getId();
            unset($custsess);
        }
    }

    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);

    if (!$customer->getId()) {
        $this->_fault('not_exists');
    }

    if (!is_null($attributes) && !is_array($attributes)) {
        $attributes = array($attributes);
    }

    $result = array();

    foreach ($this->_mapAttributes as $attributeAlias=>$attributeCode) {
        $result[$attributeAlias] = $customer->getData($attributeCode);
    }

    foreach ($this->getAllowedAttributes($customer, $attributes) as $attributeCode=>$attribute) {
        $result[$attributeCode] = $customer->getData($attributeCode);
    }

    return $result;
}
```